# how to save a file in a path and access it from a different path PHP using ../../

Tags: php, mysql, save

I need to save a file to a MySQL database when I upload it. I got this to work but when I upload it the directory goes back 3 times using `../../../`. When I need to access it I only need to got backwards 2 times. How do I save so that it can be assessed at anywhere.
Here's the upload code.

```
$nameCover = $_FILES['cover']['name'];
$target_dirCover = "../../../contentStorage/covers/";
$target_fileCover = $target_dirCover . $_FILES["cover"]["name"];
```

Here is what the
[MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGzfz.png) looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good idea to use a path like `../../..` instead use the absolute path such:

**Linux**

```php
$nameCover = $_FILES['cover']['name'];
$target_dirCover = "/home/user/web/contentStorage/covers/";
$target_fileCover = $target_dirCover . $_FILES["cover"]["name"];
```

**Windows**

```php
$nameCover = $_FILES['cover']['name'];
$target_dirCover = "c:\\path\\to\\contentStorage\\covers\\";
$target_fileCover = $target_dirCover . $_FILES["cover"]["name"];
```

In both cases, you can use and check the path with [PHP realpath function](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.realpath.php)